# Javascript- Sum (Table) of particular Column of calculated inputs

Tags: javascript

pardon me as I am in early stages of web development. Here I would like to take the total (sum) from the series of rows which as been calculated as shown below. Please help me in generating the code for calculating each rows of Amount column. I tried all the methods including other answers in stackoverflow and quora  but no avail and left in the sea of confusion. Any help in this regard would be much appreciated please (either comment or fiddle or answer)

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Steel</td>
        <td><input id="qty1" type="text" oninput="cal1()" /></td>
        <td><input id="rate1" type="text" oninput="cal1()" /></td>
        <td><input id="amt1" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cement</td>
        <td><input id="qty2" type="text" oninput="cal2()" /></td>
        <td><input id="rate2" type="text" oninput="cal2()" /></td>
        <td><input id="amt2" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>TOTAL<input id="tot1" type="text" /></td>
        //Here I want to know how to get the total sum of amt1(id) and amt2 (id) automatically
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function cal1(){
      var x1 = document.getElementById('qty1').value;
      var x2 = document.getElementById('rate1').value;
      var x3 = document.getElementById('amt1').value;
      var x4 = x1 * x2;
      amt1.value = x4;
     }
    function cal2(){
      var y1 = document.getElementById('qty2').value;
      var y2 = document.getElementById('rate2').value;
      var y3 = document.getElementById('amt2').value;
      var y4 = y1 * y2;
      amt2.value = y4;
     }
   //Here I want to know the sum of id(amt1) and (amt2)
  </script>
```

I have got the output for calculating each row of the "Amount" column. However, unable to get the total of the Amount Column as in this link- http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=kales0&s=9

Answer (score 0):

Check out rudimentary example on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/punpa/pen/grWAmV) to get you started.

In essence your cal1 and cal2 functions were not doing what you intended, and also you probably want another function that calculates the total, every time the amt1 or amt2 value change.

Javascript code:

```
function cal1() {
    var x1 = document.getElementById('qty1');
    var x2 = document.getElementById('rate1');
    var x3 = document.getElementById('amt1');

    x3.value = parseInt(x1.value) + parseInt(x2.value);

    calcTotal();
}

function cal2() {
    var y1 = document.getElementById('qty2');
    var y2 = document.getElementById('rate2');
    var y3 = document.getElementById('amt2');

    y3.value = parseInt(y1.value) + parseInt(y2.value);

    calcTotal();
 }

function calcTotal() {
    var amt1 = document.getElementById('amt1');
    var amt2 = document.getElementById('amt2');
    var tot1 = document.getElementById('tot1');

    tot1.value = parseInt(amt1.value) + parseInt(amt2.value);
}
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>calculation exercise</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Steel</td>
      <td><input id="qty1" type="text" oninput="cal1()" /></td>
      <td><input id="rate1" type="text" oninput="cal1()" /></td>
      <td><input id="amt1" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cement</td>
      <td><input id="qty2" type="text" oninput="cal2()" /></td>
      <td><input id="rate2" type="text" oninput="cal2()" /></td>
      <td><input id="amt2" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>TOTAL<input id="tot1" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```